# OpenCV c# какая версия framework

Tags: c#, opencv, framework

При попытке установи Install-Package OpenCV -Version 2.4.11 вы дает ошибку

> Не удалось установить пакет «OpenCV 2.4.11». Вы пытаетесь установить
>   этот пакет в проект, требуемая версия платформы которого —
>   «.NETFramework,Version=v4.5», но в пакете нет ссылок на сборки или
>   файлов содержимого, совместимых с этой платформой. Дополнительную
>   информацию можно получить у автора пакета.

Какая должна быть версия framework?

Comment: требуемая версия платформы которого — «.NETFramework,Version=v4.5»

Comment: 4.5 используемая версия